# Getting value from shared preference after clear data

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am setting some value in shared preference at the time when my app is getting installed.

Now if the user has done clear data then that will be gone and the user has not installed the app again which means that value won't be set again.

So is there any way I can get that value which I have stored in preference at the time of installation of an app after the user has cleared the data?

Comment: If user clear data then you can't get that data from shared preference . You can check sharedpreference on launcher activity's onResume() if data is not there then again add that data in sharedpreference.

Comment: Actually the value that I am storing at installation is the time when my app is being installed. So adding that in activity's onResume() again when data is being cleared will give different value.
 I hope you got my problem.

Comment: you can't do anything during installation. It is not possible

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko To be exact I am doing in up gradation of my app by comparing version numbers of the app. If my App is upgraded then only I am setting that time value.

Comment: You can store a copy of that data in other Sharedpreference and fetch it from there if needed.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati But all Sharedpreference  will get cleared if user has done clear data right?

Comment: Don't use defaultSharedPreferences. create two sharedPreferences with different names, clear only the one which user wants to clear. Other wont get affected with that. If you want only one sharedPreference, instead of clearing you can remove() the data by specifying the key. e.g: remove("keyForOriginalData").

Comment: @ManishPrajapati but I am not clearing or removing it manually I am taking about the case when user goes to Settings -> App -> "My App" -> Clear Data.
In that case each and every data stored in shared preferences is lost.

Comment: In that case, you can store data in firebase. You dont have to do much coding for that either, just a few lines of code to store and retrieve from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

You can`t restore data without saving all your data into the server after onPause, but you can use sync account adapter [Sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/) or Firebase for storing this data and restore it after application reinstall. Remember that sync is asynchronously and some data may be lost. In other cases if you have WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE permission you can save data on SD card, but not in the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can not able to retrieve the saved data after user clicks on clear data and clear cache button. Because all the data stored using Shared Preferences are store in the local only we are not using any server. The best example is when you already logged into Facebook and you are doing the same(Clear data and cache) for Facebook app, then again when you will open Facebook, it will ask you to login again because your all credentials are stored in local that is it may be using Shared Preference or SQLite.